# Kindle version of WikiTravel?

Tags: planning, electronic-items, guidebooks

Is everyone's favorite open content travel guide, [WikiTravel](http://wikitravel.org), available in some sort of Kindle / off-line format? Since I'll be travelling around, I won't have internet access. However I do have a kindle, so is there anyway to put wikitravel pages for areas I'll be visiting on my kindle before I leave?

Comment: If you have the 3G kindle, you have free online access to it in over 100 countries ;)  I used mine right throughout Europe, until I broke it :(

Answer (score 11):

I don't know about a specific Kindle version, but if I have a limited number of destinations with some long WikiTravel articles, I just save the pages:

Option 1, in Google's Chrome browser open the print preview and then save the page as PDF, then just copy that PDF to your Kindle, it's okay in vertical screen rotation and very readable in horizontal.

Option 2, on the left-hand menu choose 'Printable version' then save the complete web page. You can now use that HTML directly or use a tool like [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert the html into mobi format which can be read by your Kindle.

In some cases I do both to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Yeah that's an easy and quick way, but oftentimes there are numerous pages per region (e.g. a different page per city/area), so I'd like to have them all.

Answer (score 7):

Dolphin Books is producing E-Book versions of parts of Wikitravel at $2 each - suitable for the Kindle.

For example, their [London e-book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RCTCW2).

Depending on where you're going, they may have a  guide for you that works.

A review from Amazon:

> This is about 75 Kindle pages of Creative Commons (or in some cases,
>   public domain) materials. Of limited value, but also not expensive.

Answer (score 7):

http://code.google.com/p/oxygenguide/

OxygenGuide is an electronic world travel guide for use when traveling abroad with no (or expensive) Internet connection. You can use it on your PDA, notebook, cellphone or computer.

OxygenGuide is basically an offline version of the excellent Wikitravel collaborative travel guide, restructured for use on potentially small devices.

Supported hardware:

```
All laptops and netbooks
Android
Kindle
Nokia smartphones
```

Answer (score 7):

Similar to Peter Handorff's solution, I use Instapaper to save articles and send them to my Kindle. You can send articles individually.

If you want to combine articles into a 'book', create a folder in Instapaper, then move all the relevant articles to that folder. In the right sidebar you'll see a download link for Kindle. This produces a nicely wrapped 'magazine' — with a table of contents and chapter markers for each article — that you can copy to your Kindle via USB or Calibre.

It's free to use; Instapaper offers a subscription but you don't need it for the methods described above. http://instapaper.com/

Comment: Note (to be fair to competition) that there are other similar products: [pocket](http://getpocket.com/) and the free/open source [wallabag](https://www.wallabag.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use calibre for the process, you can also (1) open print preview (2) save pdf (3) email it to your kindle at *kindusername*@kindle.com. Your kindle will download the attachment the next time you're connected to wifi.

Answer (score 2):

As you are asking not only for a kindle version, but also other sorts of offline version, I'd like to point out the Kiwix reader for Wikivoyage. (Since the time the question was asked, wikitravel split up into two forks and wikivoyage seems to be the more up to date one).

It's an app for both [iOS and Android](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wikivoyage:Kiwix) which saves an offline copy of all wikivoyage articles. This is especially useful, as you don't need to download all the articles you want one by one.

One downside is that it's not always the most current version of the article. If I'm not wrong it's updated every few months, which for most purposes is still okay.